# Canceling installation/unistallation doesnt always cancel the installation/uninstallation in WiX

Tags: wix, vsix

I've created an MSI using WiX to install a Visual Studio Extension (VSIX).

However, I found that if I press Cancel during the last few seconds of the installation/uninstallation, it is completely ignored and installation/uninstallation proceeds as if cancel was never pressed at all.

How do I rectify this behavior so that the Cancel event is handled properly everytime?

Answer (score 0):

Wix compiles down to a Windows Installer MSI, and most of the funny edge cases come from there. A very careful reading of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372860(v=vs.85).aspx sometimes helps, but I'm afraid that the are a **lot** of weird behaviours in Windows Installer.